# If statement - how to check if a path contains a file

Tags: shell, powershell, powershell-3.0

I just started playing around with powershell so execuse my newbie mistakes.
I am **searching** for a file and I'm storing the path of the file in a variable, then I want to check if in that path there are specific files and then **delete** them. I cant find much help on this stuff, I think there is a problem in the if statement but I cant figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
$startDirectory = ".\somepath\"
$FindFileXml = Get-Childitem $startDirectory 

$StorePaths = Get-Childitem $FindFileXml -include "file.xml" -recurse 
if($StorePaths -eq "somefile.cs" -and "diffrentfile.cs")
{
    Remove-Item "somefile.cs"
    Remove-Item "diffrentfile.cs"
}
else{
Write-host "file not found!"
}
```

UPDATE:

```
$StorePaths = Get-Childitem $FindFilterXml-Filter "file.xml" -recurse

$StorePaths | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory 
| Get-ChildItem | 

Where-Object {($_.Name -eq 'GeneratedCode.cs') -or ($_.Name -eq 'TypedEnums.cs')} 

| Remove-Item
```

will this store the path of File.xml in $StorePaths ? if so how can i copy it e.g Copy-Item $StorePath.name .\somepath?

Comment: Yes, this will store the path of file.xml in $storePaths. You can copy it by piping it to the copy-item cmdlet, e. g. : `$StorePaths | Copy-Item -Destination 'your_path'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *don't* need a if statement here. Just filter your result for the files you want to delete and *pipe* them to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet:

```
$StorePaths | 
    Where-Object {($_.Name -eq 'somefile.cs') -or ($_.Name -eq 'diffrentfile.cs')} |
    Remove-Item
```

---

**Update:**
This example only deletes the files in the directory where a file.xml is present:

```
Get-Childitem $FindFileXml -Filter "file.xml" -recurse | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory |
    Get-ChildItem |
    Where-Object {($_.Name -eq 'somefile.cs') -or ($_.Name -eq 'diffrentfile.cs')} |
    Remove-Item
```

Comment: I tried your code but the files are not being deleted. The `file.xml` is always in a folder with `somefile.cs` and `diffrentfile.cs` what could be the problem?

Comment: Ah, just saw that you use the `-include` parameter. Can you omit it?

Comment: Hmm, i have to find the path of the file.xml first because there are different location of the file file.xml . could there be another solution other than using `-include` parameter?

Comment: You are a life saver! Works perfectly Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143415/discussion-between-john-johnson-and-martin-brandl).